# Does each Windows Store application have its own network level/layer that can be accessed?

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I would like to get access to the network layer of my application to add a proxy programatically. I understand setting proxy with HTTPClientHandler is possible but for the project I am working on, I would need to get all app requests (whether it is HttpClient, WebView, etc) to go through this proxy. Something like an app level proxy.

The iOS SDK has [NSURLProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This allows developers to get access to all requests made by the application.

Does the Windows Store API have something similar? If it is not accessible publicly, where could I start looking for this implementation. Maybe I could update the object through reflection.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you wait for Windows 8.1 release?

Comment: Yes I should be able to. Does Windows 8.1 have this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

WebView in 8.1 has mechanism to intercept resource requests and replace them with your own. See http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-179 around 42 minutes. Basically you will have to create your own implementation of [`IUriToStreamResolver.UriToStreamAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.iuritostreamresolver.uritostreamasync.Aspx) that uses HttpClient to get all of your data through proxy.

Comment: Hmm, I'll try this out! It seems that this is only for local stream uris, so if the source of the WebView was google.com, I'm assuming it wouldn't go through my implementation of IUriToStreamResolver.UriToStreamAsync?

Comment: I don't think there is a problem since you can use HttpClient to load data from any external source, google included. How ether without knowing your exact requirements I can not say for sure if it will work for you or not.

Comment: My apologies, I meant the WebView would not be able to load any uri using IUriToStreamResolver.UriToStreamAsync and WebView.NavigateToLocalStreamUri. 


I implemented IUriStreamResolver and when I called NavigateToLocalStreamUri("http://google.com") it threw an exception. It seems that it has to be a local stream uri (created with WebView.BuildLocalStreamUri).


Do you know if it is possible to use IUriToStreamResolver with the regular WebView.Navigate method? Unfortunately I was not able to find another way to use IUriToStreamResolver.

Comment: I was unable to get this method working... I am getting unexpected COM exceptions. So it looks like you are out of luck on this one.

Comment: I see, well thanks for looking into it Denis. Appreciate your help!